# Find all values of a complex constant c where a function is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function defined by $f(x+iy) = x^2-y^2+2cxy$ , where $c$ is a complex constant.

In other words, $c=c_1+ic_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

We also define $x,y,c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Find the values of $c$ for which $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$.

--

I began this question  by expanding the constant term in the definition of the function:

$h(x+iy)=x^2+y^2+2c_1xy+i(2C_2xy)$.

From this I worked out the Cauchy Riemann equations by taking $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2+2c_1xy$ and $v(x,y)=2C_2xy$.

Hence, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2x+2c_1y$ , $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-2y+2c_1x$ , $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=2c_2x$ , $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=2c_2y$.

Then, for $h$ to be analytic in $\mathbb{C}$, all of these partial derivatives must satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations. It is here that I am stuck and am not sure how to work out the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: *“... all of these partial derivatives must equal zero”* – No. They must satisfy the CR equations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have edited to avoid reader's confusion and I'll give it another crack with this updated knowledge!

Comment: Your choices for u(x,y) and v(x,y) look correct, so all you need to do from here is **∂u/∂x=∂v/∂y *and* ∂u/∂y=-∂v/∂x** (note the negative on the second equation); then as others have noticed you can solve for the values of c which cause f(z) to be analytic. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CR equations are
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\;.
$$
The former is $2x+2c_1y=2c_2x$, from which immediately you get $c_1=0, c_2=1$. These values satisfy automatically the latter.

Thus the only complex value of $c$ to have $f$ analytic is $c=i$.

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simplification that might help:

Note that $z^2 = (x+iy)^2 - x^2-y^2 + 2xyi$, so
$g(z) = f(z) - z^2$ will be analytic **iff** $g$ is.

Note that $g(z) = 2 (c-i) xy$.

To finish, note that $g(z) \in \{ \lambda (c-i) | \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \}$. If $g$ is a non constant analytic function it is an open map, so if $c \neq i$ we obtain a contradiction. Hence $c=i$.